# Sort Product List to show Out of Stock items after in stock items with magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, product-list, magento-community, stock

The product list pages are currently set to show out of stock products. I would like to show these products after the In Stock items. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `catalog_product_collection_load_before` event.

And in the observer:

```
public function modifyProductCollection(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    //catalog_product_collection_load_before
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                array('_inventory_table' => $collection->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_item')),
                "_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id",
                array('is_in_stock')
            )
            ->order('is_in_stock DESC')
            ->order('created_at DESC');
}
```

*Note: Tested on 1.7.0.2, I guess it will work on 1.8, too.*

Comment: The disadvantage to this approach is that not all out of stock products will be in the correct position as the is_in_stock entry doesn't take isSalable in account.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning how all of this works. Where do I need to make these changes?

Comment: You will need a new module for this. Search on the net for creating module with observer, there are many tutorials.