# Magento 2: Show Out of Stock items after in stock items

Tags: magento2, catalog, out-of-stock

I want to show Out of Stock items after in stock items. I found solution [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/sort-product-list-to-show-out-of-stock-items-after-in-stock-items-with-magento-1), but its for Magento 1.8. I need same for Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code to sort according to current direction (By ASC or By DESC)

```
  $collection = $subject->getCollection();
  $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
         ['_inventory_table' => 'cataloginventory_stock_item'], 
         "_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id", ['is_in_stock']
  );
  $collection->getSelect()->order(['is_in_stock ' . $currentDirection]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a module which does exactly this:

https://github.com/tuyennn/magento2-outofstockatlast

I tested in Magento 2.4.3-p2 and confirmed it working.