# How to sort product in search result?

Tags: magento-1.9, sorting

I want to sort product search result by in stock and then show out of stock products. Currently my search result is mixing in stock & out of stock items. 
Please help to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/MaximusDecimus/ShowInStockFirst  This may Help You.
Also try by creating event/observer 
[Sort Product List to show Out of Stock items after in stock items with magento 1.8](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/sort-product-list-to-show-out-of-stock-items-after-in-stock-items-with-magento-1)